# How to add, resize, position, change color and font style of text field with user inputs inside canvas in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i'm looking for any javascript library which provides functionality to add, delete, resize, position, color change and change font style by taking user inputs.

just no idea from where to start. please suggest me how can I start.